# Assign an array to *mut c_void

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I am writing bindings for a library, where I have a function with a parameter of type `void*` aka `*mut c_void` in Rust. I have to assign an array to this parameter, how can I do this in Rust?

I've tried casting, `transmute`, it doesn't work (`transmute` says that `c_void` and `[u8]` are of different sizes). If it matters, I am getting the slice from a vector.

**UPDATE**: Perhaps it would be correct to somehow use vec.as_mut_ptr() instead?

**PLAYPEN**: http://is.gd/KjgduZ

Comment: this is the other way around, but the explanation is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31238747/1103681

Comment: @ker Could you write an answer?

Comment: i dunnow. I'd just be ripping off @DK's answer 1:1

Comment: @ker This situation is a bit different. I wasn't able to get something to work using that answer.

Comment: please show the code you have tried. The best would be an example in the playpen: http://play.rust-lang.org . Then I will explain how to make your code work and why some changes need to be done. I'm aware that it won't compile, but just add the ffi that you want and the code how you tried to call it.

Comment: how would the C-code know how long the array is? or is that hardcoded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The API you have described looks very suspicious. Remember that there are actually no "arrays" in C - arrays are just another name for pointers to the beginning of multiple values of the same type which are laid continuously in the memory. Therefore, it is impossible to just "assign" an array in C. There are two concepts which may be understood as "assigning" to an array: first, assigning a pointer to the beginning of an array somewhere:

```c
const char *s1 = "hello";
const char *s2 = "world";

const char *s = s1;  // make `s` contain a pointer to "hello"
s = s2;  // make `s` contain a pointer to "world"
```

Second, it is copying certain pieces of data from one pointer to another, which is usually done with `memcpy()` or something like it:

```c
const char *s1 = "hello";

char s2[5];
memcpy(s2, s1, 5);  // copy 5 bytes from the memory pointed at by `s1` to the memory pointed at by `s2`
```

You can probably see now what I mean when I'm saying that your API is suspicious. Your callback function is given a `void *`, however, there is no indication which "array copy" method should be used.

If it is the first one, i.e. copying the pointer to the beginning of an array, then `void *` type is extremely unhelpful. It does not say how this pointer should be represented. It looks like that you're trying to do exactly this; however, it won't work as you probably think. Here is a compiling variant of your code (note that it is wrong and will most likely crash your program; see below):

```rust
#![feature(libc)]
extern crate libc;

use libc::c_void;

pub extern fn demo(data: *mut *mut c_void) {
    let mut vec = vec!(1, 2, 3);
    unsafe {
        *data = vec.as_mut_ptr() as *mut c_void;
    }
}
```

(Note that you can call `as_mut_ptr()` on a `mut` variable containing a vector directly due to autoderef)

The parameter type is now not just `*mut c_void` but `*mut *mut c_void`, that is, it is a pointer to `*mut c_void`. This way the program which calls this function could pass a pointer to a local variable of type `void *` to this function and get a pointer to an actual array, something like

```c
void *data;
some_struct.callback_fn(&data);  // pointer to `demo` is stored in `some_struct`
// data is now whatever your `demo` function has assigned
```

Note that you just *can't* sensibly make `demo` accept just `*mut c_void` because the only thing you can do with it is to reassign the parameter itself, but reassigning the parameter will reassign only this parameter value, i.e. the local variable this parameter represents. This can't be observed outside of the function. In other words, the following code (which is also a variant of the one you provided):

```rust
pub extern fn demo(mut data: *mut c_void) {
    let mut vec = vec!(1, 2, 3);
    data = vec.as_mut_ptr() as *mut c_void;
}
```

does nothing, and Rust is glad to point this out:

```
<anon>:6:20: 6:28 warning: variable `data` is assigned to, but never used, #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default
<anon>:6 pub extern fn demo(mut data: *mut c_void) {
                            ^~~~~~~~
<anon>:8:5: 8:9 warning: value assigned to `data` is never read, #[warn(unused_assignments)] on by default
<anon>:8     data = vec.as_mut_ptr() as *mut c_void;
             ^~~~
```

The reason I said that the code with `*mut *mut c_void` is wrong is that it actually violates memory safety. If you create a `Vec` instance and store it to a local variable, when this variable goes out of scope, the vector itself will be destroyed and the memory it wraps will be freed. Therefore, every pointer obtained from it using `as_ptr()` or `as_mut_ptr()` will become invalid.

There are several ways to work this around, the simplest one is to just `forget()` the vector:

```rust
use std::mem;

let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
*data = vec.as_mut_ptr() as *mut c_void;
mem::forget(vec);
```

This way the vector is "forgotten" - its destructor won't be called. This way, however, a memory leak is introduced to your program. With each call of `demo()` a bit more memory will be allocated but not freed, so eventually your program will use all of the available memory and probably crash afterwards. It is a sensible things to do in some context, however, especially in low-level code. For example, your API may specify that it will only call this function once.

Another problem with this approach is a logical consequence of the above one. Your API may specify who should free the memory at the pointer provided to it. For example, it may require passing a memory allocated with `malloc()` so it then will free it with `free()` by itself. Or it may specify that you should define another function which will be called when all allocated memory should be freed. Either way is somewhat inconvenient to implement in Rust; I won't go in details on how to do it unless this is indeed your case. Anyway, your API must clearly specify the owner of the memory, and you *should* take it into account because Rust is much more explicit about ownership.

Another possibility is that your API requires you to copy some data to the memory specified by `void *` pointer. In other words, its implementation contains a code like this one:

```c
char buffer[256];
some_struct.callback_fn(buffer);
```

and it expects that after `callback_fn` invocation the `buffer` is filled with data.

If this is the case, the API must, naturally, specify the maximum number of bytes in the buffer that your program may use, and your `demo` function may look like this:

```rust
use std::ptr;
use libc::c_void;

pub extern fn demo(data: *mut c_void) {
    let vec: Vec<u8> = vec!(1, 2, 3);
    unsafe { 
        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(vec.as_ptr(), data as *mut u8, vec.len());
    }
}
```

(alternatively, you can convert `data` to `&mut [u8]` with [`std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts_mut.html) and use either [`clone_from_slice()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.clone_from_slice) method or [`bytes::copy_memory()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/bytes/fn.copy_memory.html) function, but they both are unstable, so they can't be used on stable Rust)

In this case you should be especially careful not to overflow the buffer provided by the calling program to you. Its maximum size should be specified in the API.

Another concern is that copying an array is simple only for byte arrays (`char *` on C side, `&[u8]/&mut [u8]` on Rust side). When you start using larger types, like `i32`, you will get a possibility for portability problems. For example, in `C` `int` does not have a defined size, so you just can't blindly convert `&[i32]` to `&[u8]` with four times the original size and copy bytes from it to `*mut u8`. These problems should be taken care of very carefully.

Comment: Wow, now this is an answer that will surely help people in need like me. Indeed, the C code does give me the max length, I will try your last code sample, thanks!

Comment: You are a life-saver, thanks so, so much. IMHO, this should be added somewhere in the book, the FFI chapter is still very vague. Again, thanks :)